# Why is a new item being added?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

One teacher can have many subjects and vice versa, one subject can have many teachers. That is, here is mtm((ef > 5.0). That's exactly what I did. But when a new teacher is added, new subjects are created. How to fix this?

Before adding a teacher

- Chemistry
- PE
- Biology

Then I'm adding a new teacher

```
    // for example subjects = ["Biology", "Chemistry"] 

    await _db.Teachers.AddAsync(new Teacher
    {
          ...
          Subjects = subjects,
    });
```

After adding a teacher

- Chemistry
- PE
- Biology
- Chemistry
- Biology

Teacher model

```
public class Teacher : User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public IList<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

User model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Subject model

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu okay, i gonna fix it

Comment: Where are the subjects coming from? You would have to pull the existing subjects from the database first, and then add them to the existing list of subjects for the teacher (one way of doing it).

Comment: @insane_developer if i'm adding existing subject then i gets an error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Subjects' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: @olegshmel in the same DbContext instance that you save, you retrieve the subjects to be added (without disabling tracking). You don't set a new list to the Subjects, as you are doing. You get the current list from the DbContext and then you add the new ones you retrieved previously. This will not try to save "new" subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pitfall with web applications and EF when you pass entities around, or cases where you create new references to related entities and assume that EF will relate them.

If you have a collection of Subjects passed into your method something like:

```
public void CreateTeacher(string name, IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
{
    var teacher = new Teacher
    {
        Name = name,
        Subjects = subjects
    };
    context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

where the subjects list had Chemistry and Biology. It looks innocent enough, but between web request calls those Subjects coming in are just deserialized objects. They are not known to the DbContext, so when they are associated with the new Teacher they are treated as new subjects. Be default EF conventions will treat a column named Id as an Identity so this will result in two new subjects added to the Subject table with names Chemistry & Biology.

To avoid this behaviour we need to do one of two things: Associate the subjects to the DbContext (after checking to ensure they aren't already associated) or ensure we use only subjects that have been fetched by the DbContext.

Example: Fetching subjects from DbContext

```
public void CreateTeacher(string name, IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
{
    var subjectIds = subjects.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var dbSubjects = context.Subjects.Where(x => subjectIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
    var teacher = new Teacher
    {
        Name = name,
        Subjects = dbSubjects
    };
    context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Typically we would re-factor the method to just pass in Subject Ids and use the DbContext to load them. No need to send all subject fields over the wire.

Example: Associating with the DbContext

```
public void CreateTeacher(string name, IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
{
    var subjectIds = subjects.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    foreach(var subject in subjects)
    {
        if(!context.Subjects.Local.Any(x => x.Id == subject.Id)
            context.Subjects.Attach(subject);
    }
    var dbSubjects = context.Subjects.Local
        .Where(x => subjectIds.Contains(x => x.Id))
        .ToList();

    var teacher = new Teacher
    {
        Name = name,
        Subjects = dbSubjects
    };
    context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This assumes that all Subjects coming in are valid and reference an existing row in the database. If you can mix in new subjects then this gets a fair bit more complex. (checking subject IDs for 0 etc.)  By going to `context.Subjects.Local` we don't hit the DB, we just check the DbContext cache for any loaded subjects before attaching the subject. Once attached it will be part of the `.Local` set so we can find our subjects without touching the DB.

Generally fetching the data from the DB is safer and simpler. Fetching entities by ID is quite fast and helps ensure that the data state supports the passed in references.

Answer (score -2):

I think what Sergey is proposing is close to what is required in that I think you need to move your adding of the relationship outside of the adding of the teacher record. Just the second from last line changed from his proposal.

```cs
var teacher=new Teacher
    {
          ...
                   // don' t use this Subjects = subjects,
    });

 _db.Teachers.Add(teacher);
 teacher.Subjects = tvm.Subjects;
 await _db.Teacher.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. But I am getting a new error: ""The instance of entity type 'Subject' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked"".
 In theory, it is no longer relevant to the question. Therefore, if I solve it, I will mark your answer as correct